# HasOne and HasMany for the same Table cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

i'd like to set `hasOne` and `hasMany` to same `model`,in a part of my code i need only 1 result, but in other part i need all result (Objects from type Client that will return for a table in my site):

```
    $this->hasOne('Vendas')
    ->setForeignKey('id_cliente')
    ->setBindingKey('id')
    ;

    $this->hasMany('Vendas')
    ->setForeignKey('id_cliente')
    ->setBidingKey('id');
```

This is possible, or i made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manual https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html. Read the *whole* page carefully.

- **className**: the class name of the table being associated to the current model. If you’re defining a ‘User hasOne Address’ relationship, the className key should equal ‘Addresses’.
- **conditions**: an array of find() compatible conditions such as ['Addresses.primary' => true]

Define the class name and conditions you need for your assocs.

```
    $this->hasOne('Foo', [
        'className' => 'Foo',
        'conditions' => [/* whatever you need*/]
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('Bar', [
        'className' => 'Foo',
        'conditions' => [/* whatever you need*/]
    ]);
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up the alias and the class name for `hasMany` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is 1-* you should define the relationship as `hasMany()`. Then you write a query for one result and a query for multiple results